# Can not find symbol STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload an image to firebase I have the following code that is trowing the error above

```
     //getting the storage reference
        StorageReference sRef = storageReference.child(SyncStateContract.Constants.STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(filePath));
```

Ihave the class Constants created with this code to define the STORAGE_PATHS_UPLOADS

```
    package com.otemainc.thevendor;
     public class Constants {
     public static final String STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS = "uploads/";
     public static final String DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS = "uploads";
}
```

What could be wrong with the code to cause this error?

Comment: What is `SyncStateContract`

Comment: It is a class in the  package  android.provider

Comment: Have you tried to use only `Constants.STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the SyncStateContract class as it is not necessary and is the one that is causing the error.